# how to use anonymous generic delegate in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, generics, c#-2.0, anonymous-delegates

I have a class called NTree:

```
class NTree<T>
{

    delegate bool TreeVisitor<T>(T nodeData);

    public NTree(T data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        children = new List<NTree<T>>();
        _stopTraverse = false;
    }

        ...

    public void Traverse(NTree<T> node, TreeVisitor<T> visitor)
    {
        try
        {
            _stopTraverse = false;
            TraverseInternal(node, visitor);
        }
        finally
        {
            _stopTraverse = false;
        }
    }

    private void TraverseInternal(NTree<T> node, TreeVisitor<T> visitor)
    {
        if (_stopTraverse)
            return;

        if (!visitor(node.data))
        {
            _stopTraverse = true;
        }
        foreach (NTree<T> kid in node.children)
            TraverseInternal(kid, visitor);
    }
```

When I try to use Traverse with anonymous delegate I get:

Argument '2': cannot convert from 'anonymous method' to 'NisConverter.TreeVisitor'

The code:

```
tTable srcTable = new tTable();
DataRow[] rows;
rootTree.Traverse(rootTree, delegate(TableRows tr)
    {
        if (tr.TableName == srcTable.mappingname)
        {
            rows = tr.Rows;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This however produces no errors:

```
    static bool TableFinder<TableRows>(TableRows tr)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

...

```
rootTree.Traverse(rootTree, TableFinder);
```

I have tried to put "arrowhead-parenthisis" and everything to anonymous delegate but it just does not work. Please help me!

Thanks & BR -Matti

Comment: What is the declaration of TreeVisitor ?
Be careful that you have infinite recursion in Traverse (shouldn't it call TravereInternal ?) and you are setting _stopTraverse to false twice in Traverse, so TraverseInternal won't do anything.

Comment: @timores: thanks, both fixed already :) I can fix the functionality l8r. I need to know how to do it with anonymous delegate.

Comment: We still need to see the declaration of `TreeVisitor`

Comment: @Aakas: I updated it 10mins ago. Is there some problem? I see it upmost declaration in the class :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The anonymous delegate you posted lacks the return of a boolean value (most probably the value `true` when the `if(...)` guard is `false`. Thus, it signature is actually `void (TableRow)` instead of `bool (TableRow)`, and the compiler is unable to make the conversion.

So the syntax should be:

```
tTable srcTable = new tTable();  DataRow[] rows;  rootTree.Traverse(rootTree, delegate(TableRows tr) 
    { 
        if (tr.TableName == srcTable.mappingname) 
        { 
            rows = tr.Rows; 
            return false; 
        } 
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: can you please give the syntax. I cannot add the bool keyword. As I said I've tried everything.

Comment: SORRY & THANKS! I DID NOT READ CAREFULLY.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of TreeVisitor is wrong: it introduces a new type parameter (which conflicts with the declaration of NTree). Just remove the template stuff and you get:

```
delegate bool TreeVisitor(T nodeData);
```

Then you can have:

```
class X
{

    void T()
    {
        NTree<int> nti = new NTree<int>(2);

        nti.Traverse(nti, delegate(int i) { return i > 4; });

    }
}
```

Comment: R U sure? seems to get compiled now.

Comment: That's what Resharper tells me when I have 
delegate bool TreeVisitor<T>(T nodeData);